# Should I disable the guest user on system databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, users

The guest user is disabled on our user databases but data security guys want us to disable it on system databases as well. Should I do it?

Answer (score 8):

No you shouldn't disable the guest account on the system databases.  You also shouldn't disable it on the user databases.  This will stop anyone from using SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the instance.  As long as you haven't granted any permissions in the user databases to public, and you haven't changed any of the default permissions in the databases, then the guest role poses no security risk.

Also your security team should stop making recommendations about how to secure SQL Server  until they've learned how SQL Server and it's tools work.

Comment: Regarding user databases, the guest user is disabled (no `CONNECT` permission) by default in user databases.  It should be enabled in user databases only when needed.

Comment: @DanGuzman Is this behavior documented anywhere? I'm pretty new to SQL Server, but Microsoft still seems to recommend a policy to "revoke the guest user permission to access the database if it is not required." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/guest-permissions-on-user-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @mzuther, the [model system database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-ver15#model-usage) is used as the template for all new user databases. The model database guest user is disabled when SQL Server is installed and will remain so unless someone subsequently changed it so all new user databases will have the guest user disabled by default. Security policy rules assume nothing about how a database or instance was configured; they just evaluate the current state versus recommended state for discrepancies.

Comment: So you will adhere to the guest user disabled security policy if you do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

No, don't disable the guest account within the system databases.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/batuhanyildiz/2013/03/02/guest-user-account-in-sql-server/

and the quote:

> The recommendation is not valid for master, msdb and tempdb system
>   databases. If Guest user is disabled in msdb system database, it may
>   cause some issues.